# How to power a 3V motor with AC?

Tags: power, batteries, motor, ac-dc

I want to power a 3 V motor continuously for product demo purposes. Currently, the product is powered by 2 AA batteries. I would like to change the power source so I can plug it into a 120 V wall outlet.

What are the proper steps I need to change the power supply safely? I believe a transformer is needed to step down the power.  If true, do I need perform some AC/DC conversions?

Comment: For **safety**, just check that output is not "wired" noway with input! Or use one with an old good "transformer".

Comment: You or your employers may care to consider the legal, insurance, and public image implications if someone is harmed at your demo, and it turns out that their electrical safety officer, lacking sufficient knowledge, got his or her advice by asking on a web site.

Comment: 2 V is a bit non-standard. A 3 or 3.3 V AC/DC adapter with two regular silicon diodes in series should do the job.

Comment: @winny you are right.  The motor is 3V.  I have edited the title for clarity.

Comment: Much better. Get a 3 V power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Buy an AC adapter to 3V DC. I just searched on "AC Adapter 3V" on Amazon and found many possibilities.

Do you know how much current your device draws? If not, you can estimate it by the life of the battery. AA batteries are about 2 A-hr. Example: if your batteries normally last 4 hours, the current would be about 2 A-hr/4 hr = 0.5 A.

One thing to watch for, does your device have any warnings about the type of batteries? I have a toy with a fan, and it says not to use Ni-Cad or Ni-MH batteries. Presumably because the batteries have lower internal resistance and the toy expects some internal resistance from normal alkaline batteries.

You could cut off the connector and hard wire the adapter, but I would buy the appropriate mating connector on Digikey.

Comment: Are Amazon AC to DC adapters certified to be safe? I buy adapters from reputable electronic parts distributors (Digikey) who do not sell cheap clothes and shoes.

Comment: @Audioguru I'm sure they're all certified, the issue is whether you trust the certification.

Comment: @Audioguru - "who do not sell cheap clothes and shoes" - [you sure about that](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/personal-protective-equipment-ppe/259?s=N4IgjCBcpgHAzFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG0R4wAWagVgAYQjr54B2ATlmZFY84A2XlU4ceROuwbxB1EQCZBshbymD2YCJPYaFTIm1axtIKTPaJDdeAwV0RNxsOuCGlkcuoNT5%2BNzVpf04RTjpzQL0IAF0iAAcAFygQAGUEgCcASwA7AHMQAF8ComFoEEyAE2SAWjAfXkTk3gSATzi8ZIwcVCKgA)?  ;)

Comment: Yes, Amazon sells cheap clothes and shoes and almost anything. Since they know nothing about electronics then they spec the size, weight and color. Digikey do not sell cheap clothes and shoes and have detailed specs and datasheets for all electronic items.

Comment: I order some 3V AC adapters from eBay.  I will connect the adapter to a DC power connector then to the motor.  that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

after reading the posts here and consulting some sales reps at my local electronic parts store, I was able to get an understanding of what I need to do to swap the power supply of my product.

The motor's wiring will be attached to a DC power connector, which connects to a 3V AC adapter that plugs into 120V wall outlet.  That AC adapter's price varies from few dollars from a eBay seller to $15+ on Amazon.ca.  The key here is to match the voltage of the motor to the voltage of the AC adapter.

Comment: Hi Charles, It's not the voltage rating alone but also the current rating that needs to be considered while selecting the AC adaptor.